# npx react-native link command not working in latest version of react native. How can we link custom font family in my project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, font-family, react-18

I want to use a **custom font family** in my react-native project for that when I run the command

```bash
npx react-native link
```

it shows me the error `error Unrecognized command "link"`. As I checked this may be because react-native **removed** the **link** command from the latest version of react-native.

So that I want to know how I can link the font family without using the react-native link command. I'm using the following version of **react** and **react-native**

```json
"react": "18.0.0",
"react-native": "0.69.1",
```

Lastly Thank You For Your Help In Advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the following command: `npx react-native-asset`.

Comment: Thank you so much Dimitri, It is working perfectly fine in all react-native applications

Answer (score 4):

`npx react-native link` auto-linking command is deprecated in react-native v0.60 or higher versions. Use `npx react-native-asset`.
If you don't have react-native.config.js file then create new file and paste it:

```
module.exports = {
project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
},
assets: ['./assets/fonts/'], // <- your asset folder's path
};
```

Answer (score 2):

first, create `react-native.config.js` file like below image

```
module. Exports = {
 project: {
 ios: {},
 android: {},
},
 assets: ['./src/assets/fonts/'], // path of your assert file
};
```

and then run

```
npx react-native-asset
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using expo and none of the answers solved my issue.

First I had to install - *expo install expo-font expo-app-load
ing*

Then I imported the fonts to my project (to a font's folder).

Finally I imported the following to my App.js:

```
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
```

Plus this:

```
 //Fonts
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    "SpaceMono-Regular": require("././assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf")
  });
```

last step was to use the fonts:

```
 mainTitleText:{
    fontSize:22,
    fontWeight:'700',
    fontFamily:'SpaceMono-Regular',
    color:'#202A41'
  },
```

I found the step by step solution in this tutorial(not my channel/not affiliate):
[Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBP0MfHCgo4)

If after doing all of that you still get a **warning**, I suggest you watch this [Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=viIkcDYSBrI) with additional steps using Splash Screen preventAutoHideAsync